# php array doesn't sum numbers

Tags: php, arrays, sum

why doesn't this code sum my spent_hours for each user?

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $total_spent_time += $row['spent_time'];

    if (!array_key_exists($row['activity_type'], $data)) 
    {
        $data[$row['activity_type']] = array(
            'spent_time' => array('user' => array())
        );

        $data[$row['activity_type']]['spent_time']['user'][$row['user']] = array('time' => $row['spent_time']);

        if (array_key_exists($row['user'], $data[$row['activity_type']]['spent_time']['user'])) 
        {
            $data[$row['activity_type']]['spent_time']['user'][$row['user']]['time'] += $row['spent_time'];
        }
    }
```

It gives me only the last value of the row.

Comment: this code is in a loop,set a variable to 0 before the loop, add to it.

Comment: It's not an integer value, I guess.

Comment: Show an example input row, and the resulting array using `print_r($data)`

Comment: I can't tell what you are missing because I don't have your db scheme. But I would guess you're missing another loop where you go through another dataset. Otherwise you should be simply using $total_spent_time. Show us your sql.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare counter before loop:

```
$total_spent_time = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $total_spent_time += $row['spent_time'];
}
echo $total_spent_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong some where, we need some more details of query and resultset.
You are not using $total_spent_time anywhere in the array allocation.

```
$data[$row['activity_type']]['spent_time']['user'][$row['user']] = array('time' => $row['spent_time']);
```

as you are only using $row['spent_time'], and since there is no second loop if statement executs only once per user($row['user'])
That's the reason you get only 1 value.